# python - how to have a parent invoke a method when a property changes

Tags: python, oop

I have a class that holds an array of objects (also classes).

When an item from this array fires a method, I want the class to fire a method.

From the item in the array, how can I refer to a method on the "parent" class that it is under?

Teacher is not explicitly a "super" class of student, Teacher has that student as a property.

For example

```
class Teacher:
   def __init__(self, list):
       self.array = list

   def gradeTest(self):
       print("I fired!")


list = [{student}, {student}, {nextStudent}]

class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def takeTest(paper):
        # do something with paper
        # contact student's teacher to "grade" paper
```

TLDR:

when `list[0].takeTest(paper)` fires, I'd like MasterClass to invoke `MasterClass.gradeTest()`

Comment: You can't do it in this setup. However, you could put list as an instance variable of teacher, and have a method that calls both `student.takeTest()` and `self.gradeTest()`

Comment: Another option is to have the teacher as the first/last element in the array, or give student an instance of it's teacher in it' constructor

Comment: self.array is not an instance variable? can you give an example? thank you for answering so quickly btw!

Comment: is there a way for all students to have the same "teacher" in their constructor though?

Comment: What is `MasterClass`? Did you mean mean `Teacher`? And if so, which instance of `Teacher` should be used?

Comment: I meant Teacher. The Teacher who has "student" in their self.array

Comment: Also, please post *working* examples. `list = [{student.takeTest}, {}]` is a list that contains two sets, one containing a reference to a bound method (to a presumed instance of `Student`) and the other empty.

Comment: calling a variable `list` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Haha just so you'd know the data structure =b